# SQL performance issue when joining a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, view

I have this query that its taking forever to run after joining with a query on a view. Before the join, it takes 2 minutes. The joined query itself takes 1 minute. Together, they have been going for 20+ minutes.

My questions are:

- What can I do to make this query run faster other than creating an index on the view?
- Will creating an index make this query run in a reasonable amount of time?

Thanks. Here's the query:

```
    DECLARE @year INT=2017;
WITH data AS (
    SELECT M.Brand, M.SubBrand, M.Detail, S.Units, S.OB, [PRODUCTION_DATE] = RIGHT(S.DateId,2)
    , [PRODUCTION_YEAR] = LEFT(S.DateId,4), [PRODUCTION_MONTH] = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), S.DateId),5,2) FROM [fact].[Sales] V
    LEFT JOIN [dim].[Material] M ON M.MaterialId = S.MaterialId
    INNER JOIN (SELECT [MaterialId]
                  ,[ROF]
                  ,[OB]
              FROM [Objectives].[load].[FactData_KPI_Sales_OB_ROF]
              WHERE ROF > 0) RFOB ON RFOB.MaterialId = S.MaterialId
    WHERE LEFT(S.DateId,4) > @year
)
SELECT Brand, SubBrand, Detail, [PRODUCTION_MONTH], [PRODUCTION_YEAR], OB, [01], [02], [03], [04], [05], [06], [07], [08], [09], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
FROM data
Pivot (
    SUM(Units)
    FOR [PRODUCTION_DATE] In
    ([01], [02], [03], [04], [05], [06], [07], [08], [09], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31])
    ) AS piv
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: @marc_s this is for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a temporary table instead of common table?

```
DECLARE @year INT=2017;
SELECT M.Brand, M.SubBrand, M.Detail, S.Units, S.OB, [PRODUCTION_DATE] = RIGHT(S.DateId,2)
        , [PRODUCTION_YEAR] = LEFT(S.DateId,4), [PRODUCTION_MONTH] = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), S.DateId),5,2) 
    Into #tmpData   
        FROM [fact].[Sales] V
        LEFT JOIN [dim].[Material] M ON M.MaterialId = S.MaterialId
        INNER JOIN (SELECT [MaterialId]
                      ,[ROF]
                      ,[OB]
                  FROM [Objectives].[load].[FactData_KPI_Sales_OB_ROF]
                  WHERE ROF > 0) RFOB ON RFOB.MaterialId = S.MaterialId
        WHERE LEFT(S.DateId,4) > @year

    SELECT Brand, SubBrand, Detail, [PRODUCTION_MONTH], [PRODUCTION_YEAR], OB, [01], [02], [03], [04], [05], [06], [07], [08], [09], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
    FROM #tmpData
    Pivot (
        SUM(Units)
        FOR [PRODUCTION_DATE] In
        ([01], [02], [03], [04], [05], [06], [07], [08], [09], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31])
        ) AS piv
```

Comment: Thanks Prince, I tried this solution. The SELECT INTO statement takes forever to run (20+ minutes running and nothing).

Comment: How long does it take for the select query? 
If it is big, did you set it up for partitioning?

Answer (score 0):

did you try this

```
    DECLARE @year INT=2017;
WITH data AS (
    SELECT M.Brand, M.SubBrand, M.Detail, S.Units, S.OB, [PRODUCTION_DATE] = RIGHT(S.DateId,2)
    , [PRODUCTION_YEAR] = LEFT(S.DateId,4), [PRODUCTION_MONTH] = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), S.DateId),5,2) FROM [fact].[Sales] S
    LEFT JOIN [dim].[Material] M ON M.MaterialId = S.MaterialId
    INNER JOIN   [Objectives].[load].[FactData_KPI_Sales_OB_ROF] RFOB
```

on RFOB.MaterialId = S.MaterialId 
        WHERE LEFT(S.DateId,4) > @year and RFOB.ROF > 0
    )

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks more organized that way, but unfortunately it didn't work.